# how to call functions from a static lib via a dll.

Tags: c++

I have made available a static lib to third party. they are one of the only people who dont want to use the lib in this form and are trying to use a dll with that. however, in order to do that would i just need to change those functions which will need exporting by placing 
__declspec(dllexport) in the .h and .cpp files?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little more complicated than that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Not only do you have to declare all your API functions as `__declspec(dllexport)`, but you also have to configure the compiler to compile to a `.dll`.

If you're also exporting global variables, you'll need to use deal with `__declspec(dllimport)` as well.